# ElasticSearch Mappings & Related Objects

Tags: lucene, nosql, elasticsearch

Excuse the potential n00bness of this question - still trying to get my head around this non-relational NoSQL stuff.

I've been super impressed with the performance and simplicity of ElasicSearch, but I've got a mapping (borderline NoSQL theroy) question to answer before I dive too deeply into the implementation.

Lets continue to use the Twitter examples ElasticSearch have in their documentation.

Basically, we know a tweet belongs to an user, and a user has many tweets.
The objects look something like this:

```
user  = {'screen_name':'d2kagw', 'id_str':'1234567890', 'favourites_count':'15', ...}
tweet = {'message':'lorem lipsum...', 'user_id_str':'1234567890', ...}
```

What I'm wondering is, can the tweet object have a reference to the user object?
Since I want to be able to write queries like:

```
{'query': {
  'term':{'message':'lipsum'},
  'range':{'user.favourites_count':{'from':10, 'to':30'}}
}}
```

Which I would like to return the tweets matching with the user objects as part of the response (vs. having to lazy load them later).

Am I asking too much of it?

Should I be expected to throw all the user data into the tweet object if I want to query the data in that way?

In my implementation (doesn't use twitter, this was just an elegant example) I need to have the two datasets as different indexes due to the various ways I have to query the data, so I'm not sure if I can use an object type AND have the index structure I require.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElasticSearch doesn't really support table joins that we are so used to in SQL world. The closest it gets to it is [Has Child Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-query.html) that allows limiting results in one table based on a persence of a record in another table and even here it's limited to 1-to-many (parent-children) relationship.

So, a common approach in this world would be to denormalize everything and query one index at a time.

Comment: Looks like denormalization is going to be the most likely outcome for us here.

Comment: d2kagw: What did you end up doing? I have the exact same question about how to store account data vs tweets.